# toggle button changed its state when scrolled in RecyclerView with mysqlite database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-togglebutton

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Songs songs = arrayList.get(position);

holder.favorite.setChecked(songs.getFavorite()); // this line makes me confusing.

   holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
         int r =  db.update_favorite(b,songs.getTitle(),songs.getArtist());

            compoundButton.setChecked(b);
        }
    });

}
```

the problem here is if i include this code

> holder.favorite.setChecked(songs.getFavorite());

to **onBindViewHolder**, when I change the state of toggle button and scroll down then scroll up, the state of toggle button was change itself to original state. To clarify, when toggle button state change into true from false and the user scroll down and up, the toggle button automatically change into original state which is to false.

how to make the toggle button holds the changes of state even the user scroll down? please help me.

Comment: try to remove `compoundButton.setChecked(b);`, because you are already `setChecked` by `favorite`.

Comment: @NamNH thanks for your reply. I tried your answer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my guess: the `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` is firing at a time you're not expecting.

Imagine you have 100 songs, each of which starts out as not a favorite. You activate the `CompoundButton` associated with song #5, which triggers its `OnCheckedChangeListener` and marks song #5 as a favorite in your database. Then you scroll down until song #5 isn't on screen anymore.

At some point, the `ViewHolder` that was previously associated with song #5 is going to be recycled, and then re-used to display another song. At that point in time, `onBindViewHolder()` will be called. And that will trigger this line:

```
holder.favorite.setChecked(songs.getFavorite());
```

Remember, this `ViewHolder` used to be associated with song #5, so the `CompoundButton` is **checked** before this line runs. Since the new song is **not** a favorite, this line will *change* the `CompoundButton` so that it is unchecked.

*This will trigger the `onCheckedChangeListener`.* Except at this point, the listener hasn't yet been reassigned and so still refers to song #5. Since the `CompoundButton` was changed from checked to unchecked, the listener will mark song #5 as **not** a favorite in your database.

Then the listener is reassigned and now refers to the new song. But at this point, the damage is already done.

You could solve this by simply adding

```
holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

at the beginning of `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: great explanation! thanks for that but when I tried to add holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); at the beginning of onBindViewHolder() it still not working... I did some test, I tried to remove this line holder.favorite.setChecked(songs.getFavorite()); its seems to be work because it won't change to original state after scrolling but the problem is how can i set the toggle button from database in first run?

Comment: @Mak-MakBasaya I don't know why it's not working for you. I made a small sample app (https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9031009) that reproduces the problem and then fixes it by setting the listener to null.

Comment: yes! at last my toggle button works now by your help. I analyzed your sample app and I figured out the problem. I added holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); just like what you've suggested and I added this line songs.setFavorite(b); to   holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener() and now it works like what I want.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Ben P. has beautifully explained the reason for the problem. Just want to add something to the solution.

Instead of listening to **check change** event on the switch, listen to the **click** event. On a switch, check event can be triggered on a number of other reasons. But click will be triggered only when the user clicks on the switch.

Hope I am able to explain the things properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also It solved for me after adding the below method to the adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```